# Не получается передать привилегии запускаемому процессу

Tags: winapi, delphi

Добрый день.

Использую следующий код на Delphi для запуска процесса на рабочем столе активного пользователя (пользователь, «владеющий» на момент запуска монитором) из-под службы в Windows 7 (служба запущена с правами системы):

```
function WTSQueryUserToken(SessionId: DWORD; phToken: pHandle):bool;stdcall;external 'wtsapi32.dll';
function WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId: DWORD; stdcall; external 'Kernel32.dll';
...
procedure RunApp(FilePath:string);
var
  hToken:THandle;
  si:STARTUPINFO;
  pi:PROCESS_INFORMATION;
begin
  if WTSQueryUserToken(WtsGetActiveConsoleSessionID,@hToken) then
    begin
      ZeroMemory(@si,SizeOf(si));
      si.cb:=SizeOf(si);
      si.lpDesktop:=nil;
      CreateProcessAsUser(hToken,nil,PANSIChar(FilePath),nil,nil,False,0,nil,nil,si,pi);
      CloseHandle(hToken);
    end;
end;
```

Хочу допилить этот код для того, чтобы передать запускаемому процессу права родителя (тобиш системные привилегии от службы), но сохранив условие запуска на рабочем столе активного пользователя. Пытаюсь сделать это через имперсонацию праймари токена:

```
WTSQueryUserToken(WtsGetActiveConsoleSessionID,@hToken)
...
OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES or TOKEN_QUERY or TOKEN_EXECUTE,sysToken);
DuplicateTokenEx(sysToken,MAXIMUM_ALLOWED,nil,SecurityImpersonation,TokenPrimary,hToken);
...
CreateProcessAsUser(hToken,nil,PANSIChar(FilePath),nil,nil,False,0,nil,nil,si,pi);
```

Но в результате все равно получаю процесс, запущенный с правами активного пользователя.
С WinAPI знаком плохо. Скорее всего, что-то упустил или вообще не в ту сторону пошел. Помогите с решением данной задачи.

Answer (score 1):

А если просто воспользоваться вызовом CreateProcess? Ведь тогда дочерний процесс будет запускаться от имени текущего.
UPD:
Прочитав документацию я пришел к выводу, что можно легко запустить процесс от одного из активных пользователей, либо от имени пользователя с дополнительным урезанием прав, но создать суперпользователя, выводящего информацию на текущий экран не получится. Может я не прав, тогда поправьте.
Для обхода данного ограничения рекомендую воспользоваться способом используемым в UNIX. Надо запустить два процесса: один теневой с правами системной службы и один процесс с запуском на экране, которые будут общаться между собой через сокеты localhost.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, это нарушит условие запуска на рабочем столе активного юзера, так как токен уже не будет передаваться.